# Too many arguments for format (printf function)

Tags: c, printf

Keep getting the following warning: “too many arguments for format” for the printf function below. Do not know what is causing this warning.  I provided the type values of pos and str_pos along with the printf function.  I excluded all other code as I did not think it was necessary for this question.

```
int pos;
char str_pos;
printf("The character at index %d is %c",pos,str_pos, "\n");
```

Comment: You dont want `“`, you want `"`.

Comment: close quotes after %c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The corect way of writing that `printf()` statement would be

```
printf("The character at index %d is %c\n", pos, str_pos);
```

You need to change

- `“` to `"`s.
- Use the format string correctly, including the newline.
- use `pos` and `string_pos` as the argument (not part of the format string itself), in the variadic list.

Also, I presume that variables are initialized before you're printing them.